# How to reference a dict with sphinx-autodoc?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc, cross-reference

```
:data:`~package._module._DICT_NAME`
```

Doesn't work, `_DICT_NAME` is rendered as if referenced, but with no hyperlink. Same with `:obj:`. Putting it in a function isn't an acceptable workaround.

---

**Minimal conf.py**:

```py
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = []
html_static_path = ['_static']

def skip(app, what, name, obj, would_skip, options):
    if name.startswith('_'):  # include private methods
        return False
    return would_skip

def setup(app):
    app.connect("autodoc-skip-member", skip)
```

(Actual context: [conf.py](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/blob/master/docs/source/conf.py), attempted [cross-reference](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/blob/master/deeptrain/train_generator.py#L185), the [dict](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/blob/master/deeptrain/util/_default_configs.py#L221), rendered [docs](https://dev-tg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deeptrain.html?highlight=train_generator#deeptrain.train_generator.TrainGenerator.__init__) (scroll up a little))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before trying to reference `_DICT_NAME` verify it's been put in the general index (and thus became cross-referenceable!!). If using an autodoc directive without `:undoc-members:` option the dictionary won't be include if it doesn't have a comment.  Variables can't have docstrings, so you need to use a comment `#:` before or `"""` immediately after, in the `py` for autodoc to pick it up.

Unless you are explicitly including the dictionary in the `.rst` with [`py:data:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#directive-py-data), using Domains and roles. Or, by including it in the `.rst` (using [autodata or autoattribute](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autodata), in case your `automodule` or `autoclass` doesn't pick it up and you're using directives of the autodoc extension.

Then your `_DICT_NAME` is also a private variable, so you need to check the `conf.py` settings to see if it's included like `napoleon_include_private_with_doc = True`, if you're using Sphinx Napoleon extension.

> _DICT_NAME is rendered as if referenced, but no hyperlink.

First check that it shows up documented in the final rendering of you documentation be it HTML or other. If it is included and has a comment it can be then be cross-referenced and the link will be generated.

> How to reference a dict with sphinx-autodoc?

Notice you aren't referencing with autodoc. Autodoc is extracting the docstring where you write its directive in your `.rst`. Your `:data:` cross-referencing is done by domain and roles. Although you can have referencing inside your docstring that is afterwards extracted by autodoc and finally rendered, altogether, by the Sphinx tool.

**EDIT after OP added MCVE:**

First problem I see is this, your dictionary `_DEFAULT_TRAINGEN_CFG` is in module `_default_configs.py`...

So, the cross-reference you wrote should be right `:data:~deeptrain.util._default_configs._DEFAULT_TRAINGEN_CFG\`....BUT, did you actually include this module in any `.rst` file? I don't think so, looking at [deeptrain.util.rst](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/dev_tg/blob/master/docs/source/deeptrain.util.rst) the `_default_configs.py` module is not present in any `automodule` directive, so there's nothing to reference (that's why the hyperlink isn't generated)...

**Three examples of cross-references:**

A module level dictionary, `dict_document.py`

```py
#: a comment on your dictionary
_DEFAULT_TRAINGEN_CFG = dict(
    dynamic_predict_threshold_min_max = None,
    checkpoints_overwrite_duplicates  = True,
)
```

1. One possible `dict_document.rst`

```sh
dic_document module
===================

.. automodule:: dict_document

some text to break, lets reference:

:data:`_DEFAULT_TRAINGEN_CFG` WORKS !!
```

The result:

[image]

2. Another possible `dict_document.rst`

```sh
dic_document module
===================
Lets try a more explicit apporach:

.. automodule:: dict_document
    :exclude-members: _DEFAULT_TRAINGEN_CFG

    .. autodata:: _DEFAULT_TRAINGEN_CFG

some text to break, lets reference:

:data:`_DEFAULT_TRAINGEN_CFG` WORKS !!
```

The result:

[image]

3. One more possible `dict_document.rst`

```sh
dic_document module
===================

Lets try without using autodoc:

.. py:module:: Sphinx_test.dict_document

.. py:data:: _DEFAULT_TRAINGEN_CFG
    :type: dict[str, Any]

Notice the docstring wasn't extracted from .py and included here because autodoc directives weren't used.

some text to break, lets reference:

:py:data:`~._DEFAULT_TRAINGEN_CFG` WORKS !!
```

The result:

[image]

---

**Minimal example**, without modifying `.rst`, in `module.py`; note that the comment can be empty:

```py
#:
some_dict = {"a": 1}
```

Some docstring:

```
"""
:data:module.some_dict
"""
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you include a syntactically-complete example of each proposed fix? I tried the `#:` before and `"""docs"""` after the dict, also renamed to `DICT_NAME` and put in `.module`, but no avail. I've included a minimal `conf.py`, and links to complete context.

Comment: Excellent, it works. Is there any way to shorten `:py:data:`, though? It's quite verbose - maybe with a macro defined somewhere

Comment: If you're in "the default domain" which is `:py` you can just use `:data:`, but to be on the safe side I wrote the more verbose variant. (You should keep the `:data:` as-is because otherwise folks reading your code won't understand it. Also, as a note, it's generally considered desirable to put most of the Sphinx-stuff in the .rst and leave the docstrings as clean as possible.)